# Make a change log page without affecting content or references

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, thesis

I would like to add a change log to my thesis, so that my committee can quickly see the things I have added in. Ideally, I would like to reference sections, figures and citations without altering any numbers or their ordering.  One way I can think of doing this is to add this page at the very end of the thesis.

Is there a way to achieve this while adding the page to the beginning of the document?

Comment: If the change log is located at the very end of the document and is not listed in the TOC, then it should not affect the other pages, references etc. Unless of course you have a footer/header in the form of `page X of Y`

Comment: Or you can put the changelog at the start, using an unnumbered section/chapter, and reset the page count after it (in the same way that in multipart documents where the TOC pages are numbered i, ii, etc.). Obviously, the *physical* page position (and the total number of pages) will change.

Comment: Or make the changelog a separate document and use the `xr` package to reference items in your main document.